# How to add a calculated member to all members of a level?

Tags: ssas, mdx, olap

To describe in more details, I have a cube with data about workers salaries and other fees in a big consortium (several companies). Therefore I created dimensions Time, FeeType and CompanyWorkers.

I also created a CompanyHierarchy in CompanyWorkers dimension, which obviously is `Company->Worker`.

Now I need to get average values of fees in each Company. I suppose that means I have to create a calculated member in the CompanyHierarchy.

I know how to do that for a single member:

> CREATE MEMBER
>   CURRENTCUBE.[CompanyWorkers].[CompanyHierarchy].[Company].&[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pjwxC.png).[Average]
>   AS ....

Copying this line of code for every Company in my cube seems not correct. Can I write one command to add Average to EVERY Company?

UPD: The result I'm trying to achieve is something like this:
[Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pjwxC.png)

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a calculated Measure that has your average logic. Now call this measure for your hierarchy and it will give you the average for each company. You dont need to add it for each member. To add a calculated measure you need to go to the calculations tab in the cube.

Edit : Added a sample Query

You can take a look at the sample below, I would prefer calculating averages in this manner and arranging them on the UI to look like the screen shot you shared

```
with member 
[Measures].[Reseller Sales AmountAverage]
as
case when [Geography].[Geography].currentmember is [Geography].[Geography].defaultmember then null 
else 
([Geography].[Geography].currentmember.parent,[Measures].[Reseller Sales Amount])/([Geography].[Geography].currentmember.parent,[Measures].[Reseller Order Quantity])
end
select 
{[Measures].[Reseller Sales Amount],[Measures].[Reseller Order Quantity],[Measures].[Reseller Sales AmountAverage]}
on columns,
[Geography].[Geography].members 
on rows 
from [Adventure Works]
```

[image]

Now if you want to have it displayed exactly like your picture then you can take the approach you suggested of adding average member at each level.

Comment: What do you mean by calling this measure for my hierarchy?
If I add a calculated measure like this (I omit average logic for simplicity):
CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].[Average] AS 1000, VISIBLE = 1;
What should I do next?

Comment: @Yuriy i am suggesting, instead of adding a member to your , you would be better off adding it as a measure. The Logic behind that measure would be the Sum of salaries divided by the number of distinct employees. Now you can also restirct this measure to only return results when you company dimension is used. This can be done by checking the currentmember for default value. I hope I am able to explain. If you still face an issue, share a screen shot of how the result should look like and I will provide a sample query

Comment: Thank you for the explanations. Probably I can calculate the average in the way that you offer, but a bit in a different way. I've updated the question with a screenshot. I'd really appreciate some sample query

Comment: @Yuriy you are welcome. Sure I provide you a sample. I bit occupied at the moment but will try to do it as soon as i get sometime.

Comment: @Yuriy does the above query help?

Comment: thank you for the query and sorry for a long pause. As you mention, to receive the desired view, I still need to add an average member to each member at a certain level. If I have hundreds of members (hundreds of companies), that means writing hundreds calculations. This still sounds like a problem to me...